# Secure Client/Server data transfer iphone app

Tags: php, asp.net, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

I'm searching the web for the best way to secure data transfer. We have a server with some asp.net and/or php scripts. The iPhone app calls these scripts and shows the output to the user in a user-friendly way.

The problem is that if someone decompiles the app, the url's are in plain text and visible. Therefor, they could use our servers for retreiving data and showing it on their own website or whatever.

What is the best way to secure the connection, so the data is only reachable for the iPhone app? So if you call the URL the page returns a 404 or an other error message. The main goal is to be sure only our app can use the server data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL and certificates ... what else?

Comment: Well I could use it, but I was wondering if there are other ways to handle this... Like using a webservice, or with shared keys or something. But SSL and certificates should work indeed...